# Angular Schema Form HTML Attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I've been looking over the Angular Schema Form documentation to be able to apply attributes to the elements generated at: https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md

Have been looking up and down and have found nothing. I see through defining the schema that you can define custom HTML classes:

```
htmlClass: "street foobar",  // CSS Class(es) to be added to the container div
fieldHtmlClass: "street"     // CSS Class(es) to be added to field input (or similar)
labelHtmlClass: "street"     // CSS Class(es) to be added to the label of the field (or similar)
```

But, haven't been able to find where I can apply attributes like the `data` attribute or an attribute specific to the element itself. Any resources in regards to this type of basic functionality you'd expect from form generation?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible to do purely through json schema definitions, you would have to extend Schema Form and provide your own HTML template with your custom attributes. I've had this problem myself and have had to do the very same.

I'm sure you've seen this but here's the docs on extending:

https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/extending.md